# Android Studio File Path in App Folders

Tags: android, android-studio, filepath

I added some files in res folders in my application and i need to use that files in my applicatin. I want to access that files and i tried that .

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/myapp/app/src/main/java/res/Doc1/index.html"));
```

But it does not work, how can i access that folder ?

Comment: your file selection way is wrong. in which place you can use **index.html** file.

Comment: If i add index.html to sdcard this is working. For example ;    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/dosya.html"));
out.write(stringToHTMLString(text).getBytes());
            out.close();    // This is work

Comment: yes and add permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I can already access files in sdcard. I am asking how to access files in my app folders ? Is "/myapp/app/src/main/java/res/Doc1/index.html" right or wrong ?

Comment: you use index.html file in Webview or other place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are files *on your development machine*. They are *not* files on the device. They are merely entries in your APK file. You cannot access them using `File`.

Comment: Then how can i add files to sdcard , i can reach to sd card. Also creating an assets folder, is an answer for me ?

Comment: @Ali.A: Assets also are only files on your development machine. If you use assets, you can use `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` on the asset, which you can use with Java I/O to write the content to a file. For raw resources, you can use `Resource` to get an `InputStream` on the raw resource, which you can use with Java I/O to write the content to a file.